# Facebook Comment Plugin Displays Unreachable

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-comments

I have a blog website which uses the facebook comment plugin but it displays the comment section as being "unreachable" but only on several blogs.  I'm unsure of if it has something to do with the title/url that I'm using which is something along the lines of:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/blog.php?id=12132&title=the-title-for-the-blog
```

Any ideas what would make this unreachable?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Not an error, the comment block shows up but then says "warning, this URL is unreachable"

Comment: Can you provide an example of a page URL that works, and one that doesn't? Just for comparison..

Comment: @FDL ok, `http://website.co.uk/blog.php?id=1393274100&title=welcome-to-my-blog` does not work but `http://website.co.uk/blog.php?id=1393275959&title=one-day-without-shoes,-toms-shoes` does